# Body-Parser gives undefined

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

My server.js authenticates users with the following code:

```
//API ROUTES
var apiRoutes = express.Router();
//route to auth user
apiRoutes.post('/authenticate', function(req,res){
    //find the user
    User.findOne({
        name: req.body.name
    }, function(err,user){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!user){
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found!' });
        } else if(user){
            //check if password matches
            if(user.password != req.body.password){
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password!' });
            } else{
                //user found and password is right
                //toke creation
                var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'),{
                    expiresInMinutes: 1440 // = 24h
                });

                //return information including token
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    message: 'Enjoy your token!',
                    token: token
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

But even by inserting a correct Id, the output will be always "Authentication failed. User not found!"

I insert users in MongoDb with the following code:

```
app.get('/setup',function(req,res){
    var nick = new User({
        name: 'patro',
        password: 'pass',
        admin: true
    });
    nick.save(function(err){
        if(err)throw err;
        console.log('user saved');
        res.json({success : true});
    });
});
```

And the user is correctly saved because with the following code:

```
apiRoutes.get('/users',function(req,res){
    User.find({}, function(err,users){
        res.json(users);
    });
});
```

by using POSTman I can see that the user is correctly saved:

```
  {
    "_id": "5884844c338f4813ab884eac",
    "name": "patro",
    "password": "pass",
    "admin": true,
    "__v": 0
  }
```

The name never matches because the `req.body.name` returns `undefined` as value.
Why? How I should take the name's value sent?

the body-parser is used as shown below:

```
...
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
...
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

//please no comment about the not hasing the parameters, it will be a next step :)

Comment: Are you sure that you're posting correctly? Do you get the correct name logged in console from req.body.name? Also I would advise to get the user by its objectId and not name as the same name could easily occur more than one time, Id is unique. Otherwise the code looks correct to me.

Comment: it is an example code, so of course then I will use an id field. And I'm using Postman extension for testing. However the authentication error is resulting by using this link _http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate?name=patro&password=pass_

Comment: The issue seems to be related the `req.body.name`, it gives back undefined.

Comment: Ok, if you still encounter problems then post your code where you post/put to your api and I'll have a look at it!

Comment: The issue is related to the body-parser I think, infact I added rows explaining how I set it.

Comment: edit your question with the code you post the data to `/authenticate` api. the problem lies there..

Comment: if you are using postman for the requests, you have to choose `x-www-form-urlencoded` or choose `raw` and change the type to `JSON(applicatioin/json)` instead of `Text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Following is a screenshot of postman app, how you should post the request. comment if anything unclear

Comment: Thanks a lot! So the issue was not in the code but in the usage of Postman. Your solution worked. I had to call expiresIn rather than expiresInMinutes to make the code working since the last one is not allowed.